# Pointers to function member

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, reinterpret-cast

Let me start stating I'm a self-made programming passionate, so forgive the unprofessional language, not speaking English very well I got support from translator. From what I've understood it seems that casting a pointer to an object and one of its functions member cannot be made to a dummy structure. In particular, the call to the member function cannot be made in this way:

```
#include <iostream>

struct _T{};

class Class1
{
public:
    void print()
    { std::cout << "Class1::print ...." << std::endl; }

    int sum(int value)
    { return m_dato+value; }

private:
    int m_dato { 10 };

};


int main()
{
    Class1 item;
    void(_T::*func)();
    int(_T::*fsum)(int);

    Class1* p1=&item;

    auto p2=reinterpret_cast<_T*>(p1);
    func =reinterpret_cast<void(_T::*)()>(&Class1::print);

    (p2->*func)();

    fsum =reinterpret_cast<int(_T::*)(int)>(&Class1::sum);

    auto dato=(p2->*fsum)(55);

    std::cout << "Dato: " << dato << std::endl;  // ok 65..

    std::cout << "Fine procedura ...." << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Now besides guessing that the pointer to Class1 may not be contained in the _T pointer, I don't understand why this code works without problems on all conditions (in case the class is derived and the function is virtual, in the case of multiple inheritance, in the case that the function is present only in the base class, etc ...). At the end I'm not telling the compiler to call an address of a class (Class1), that the compiler knows well, and that this function is at some offset from the class pointer and that the signature of that function is similar to the one stored later after the cast.

Comment: You cast the member function pointers to pointers to functions with the same signatures in the empty `_T` but `p2` points at a valid `Class1` (although it's a `_T*`) and the function pointers point at valid `Class1` member functions. I see nothing surprising in that it "works".

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_T`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: Dereferencing `p2` results in undefined behavior because you've told the compiler that it points at a `_T` object but it really points to a `Class1` object. One possibility then is that it appears to work.